# List always stores index object instead of only when it sets a new best score

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm creating an image recognition AI from scratch, and the following code block is supposed to store the value of a neuron when it sets a new high score, but it seems to be always doing it, or at least I can tell it's definitely not working. Here is the code:

```
for x in range(numberOfNeurons):
    for y in range(neuronTryNumber):
        neurons[x] = bestNeurons[x]
        trainingSample = random.randint(0, (len(images) - 1))  # Choose a random image in the sample file
        weights[x] = random.uniform(0.75, 1.25)
        neurons[x] = weights[x] * neurons[x]  # Modify a single neuron
        if float(arrayOfImages[trainingSample][x]) == 0.0 == float(neurons[x]) * float(arrayOfImages[trainingSample][x]):
            dataGapArray[y] = 1.0
        elif float(arrayOfImages[trainingSample][x]) > float(neurons[x]):
            dataGapArray[y] = float(neurons[y]) / float(arrayOfImages[trainingSample][x])
        elif float(arrayOfImages[trainingSample][x]) < float(neurons[x]):
            dataGapArray[y] = float(arrayOfImages[trainingSample][x]) / float(neurons[x])
        totalScore = (sum(dataGapArray) / numberOfNeurons)
        # print("Current score:", totalScore)
        if totalScore > bestScore:
            print("New Best Score!:", totalScore)
            bestNeurons[x] = neurons[x]
            totalScore = bestScore
```

Now, I should normally see a constantly increasing new high score, indicating that the code is functional, however, I sometimes see decreasing high scores. Here's an example:

```
New Best Score!: 0.7317308239784488
New Best Score!: 0.732005727847736
New Best Score!: 0.7315127892353739
New Best Score!: 0.7315127892353739
New Best Score!: 0.7249716540133387
```

Comment: If you are using print statements to debug, perhaps add the old best score before assigning it? I.E. `print("New Best Score!:", totalScore, ': Old Best Score:', bestScore)`. This way, you can see if `bestScore` was modified. If it was modified, you'll need to find out where that is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the best score instead of the total score in the last line I guess.

```
bestScore = totalScore
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the entire code, I am guesstimating a solution. Last line should be

```py
bestScore = totalScore
```

Not sure it will work out but worth a try